# How to copy and paste a selection from Excel with VBA only for cells containing values and not formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste a selection of data in an excel sheet. My issue is that the rows in the sheet contains formulas from an other sheet, and therefore some cells include formulas. The cells only contain values if a certain condition is met. Also, the sheet is dynamic so i dont know which many rows it will have from one day to the next.

I only want to select values and not the blank cells containing the formulas. I have used the xlDown function thus far, but it also includes all the cells that only have the formulas in them. I have used this code:

```
 Windows("RebalanZer_v4.11_3.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Rebal IMF_PF,BM").Select
    Range("A12:T12").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Filename).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I have seen some suggestions before on here, but i didnt quite get the hold of it (i am not that experienced using VBA). Would really appreciate if someone could show me some alternative solutions on this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How does the duplicate from your previous question not answer this?

Comment: I am not really sure how to implement the find option into my existing script to be honest. Tried to use the method suggested, but wasnt able to get an output from it. I guess that method is used to find the last row with actual data, and from there you can copy the values from first cell to the last etc. But struggled to make it work.

Comment: Instead of `Selection.End(xlDown)` you would put the column and the row number find returns.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thanks very much for taking the time to answer my question, sorry for being a bit slow on catching the point of it. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Sorry for coming back with another (possibly stupid) question here. Will this be the correct way?

Comment: Windows("RebalanZer_v4.11_3.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Rebal IMF_PF,BM").Select
    
    Dim CL As Range, i&
    Set CL = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    i = CL.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Debug.Print "Last row with data: " & i
    
    Range("A12:T12").Select
    Range(Selection, i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(Filename).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: No, `i` is currently a long, you can't pass a long to a range like that. `Range` takes ranges as arguments (or strings it can parse as ranges). [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

Comment: Ok, i see. I am not sure how to proceed with this to be honest. I dont expect to be given the answer here, you may have better things to do, but i cant see the best solution to this atm. I absolutely need to use some time to up my knowledge :)